# How to read value from prop in JointJS element?

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I try to read a prop from a JointJS element. I can see that it gets added but I can't figure out how to read the value.

```
var uml = joint.shapes.uml;

var state = new uml.State({
  name: "some name",
  prop: { myId: "some id" },
  events: ["event1", "event2"],
  attrs: {
    ".uml-state-body": {
      fill: "rgba(48, 208, 198, 0.1)",
      stroke: "rgba(48, 208, 198, 0.5)",
      "stroke-width": 1.5
    },
    ".uml-state-separator": {
      stroke: "rgba(48, 208, 198, 0.4)"
    }
  }
});

this.graph.addCell(state);
```

this does not work

```
this.paper.on("element:pointerup ", function(elementView) {
  var id = elementView.model.get("myId");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are really close... ;)

### solution with actual code

I used `prop` in getter to have full path `get("prop").myId`

than works your: `elementView.model.get("prop").myId`

https://codepen.io/Michal-Miky-Jankovsky/pen/PVXaZy

### why?

all object keys from constructor are **"attributes" for getter**

### better solution...

you can set "myId" directly on model:

```
var state = new uml.State({
   myId: "some id",
   ...
});
```

than will be available for getter as expected:

```
elementView.model.get("myId")
```